# Python: Unable to write slanted apostrophe to file

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io, character-encoding

I'm using Python 2.7 and unable to upgrade to 3.x just yet.

I need to read data from the database and write to a file.
Using the database query tool, I see the string I need to retrieve contains the following slanted apostrophe:

```
I’ve
```

When I read the database from python and simply print it to the console, I see the following.  It has converted the slanted apostrophe to a normal apostrophe.  This is actually my preferred behavior:

```
print(message)

I've
```

But when I try to write the string to a file, it instead writes the apostrophe as a question mark:

```
I?ve
```

My original code just does this:

```
file = open(path,"w")
file.write(message)
file.close()
```

To try to fix it, I did the following, but it did not help.  The question mark is still showing up:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import codecs

file = codecs.open(path,"w", "utf-8")
file.write(message)
file.close()
```

Comment: are you sure it is problem with file? Maybe problem is program which you use to display file. Better use Python to read file and check what you get from file.

Comment: It's writing an HTML file that when viewed in Chrome displays the question mark.  And when I cat the file on the console it also shows the question mark.

Comment: did you define `<meta charset="utf-8">` in `HTML`? Browser may not display some chars if it has no `charset`. Console may not display some chars if not work with `utf-8` (for example console in Windows may have this problem). You could open file in text editor or load in Python to see what you have in file.

Comment: When I open the file in Notepad, Notepad shows that the file is UTF-8, but it displays question marks.  It seems like print() is able to display the string OK.  Is there a way to redirect the print() output to second string?  I do have the utf-8 charset meta flag set.

Comment: redirecting `print()` to string make no sense - you get the same result using normal `variable = message` because `print()` doesn't change value in string. You may redirect `print()` to file `print(... file=file)` but if normal `file.write()` makes problem then redirecting `print()` to file should have the same problem because `print()` also will use `file.write()`. Did you use Python to read file and display with `print()`? Maybe better replace `'` with other char in original text `message = message.replace(...)`

Comment: I tried message.replace(...).  But message.replace("’","'") doesn't work.  message.replace("?","'") actually replaces the text, but I don't want to replace all ?.  When I print out the Hex of the string using:  `for character in string: print character, character.encode('hex')`  and it prints as '3f' or ?.  How does the print command able to print it?

Comment: don't replace `?` but original `'`

Comment: the same `3f` can be char `?` but with other value it may create `2-bytes` UTF char. So this may be problem. In one place it ca be treated as single byte and in other can be treatead as UTF.

Comment: it seems you still use `Python 2` - and maybe you should use `unicode(message)` to threats it like in `Python 3`. BTW: encoding in `Python 2` is one of biggest problem which was changed in `Python 3`

Comment: when I check `’` on Python 3 then I get code `0x2019` but on Python 2 I get three values `0xe2 0x80 0x99` - but when I use `unicode('’')` on Python 2 then it show also `0x2019`

Comment: I made a change to the Oracle database query to convert the characters from the string in the query.  That worked.  But it seems like there may be other characters like that.  It's OK for now, but I feel that I will have problems with something else later.